# Is there an easy way of making a multi language app using different screen sizes layout folders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I mean, if you do a multi language app you need to n-plicate(in my case 2 folders because I chose English/Spanish) the drawable folder, and if I want to fit in the different screens I have to make one folder for each screen size. It seems too many duplicates. Is there any other way out of this? I don't want to keep increasing the size of the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your drawables in the screen using the RelativeLayout, in this form of display you ensure to put your drawables in the same position in every screen resolution using dp instead of px as a parameter of position

Using vectors you ensure a nice quality of you images using a single file
you can use the [SVG android library](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/) and scale the vector according the screen size

hope this help